# A doubt about a trivial Dirac Delta Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

The following is, in my opinion, a quite simple integral. Yet I can figure out why the result is thy professor said to be.

The integral is:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \delta(\sin(\pi x))2^{-x}\ dx$$

By Dirac Delta properties:

$$\delta(\sin(\pi x)) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{\delta(x-k)}{|\pi \cos(\pi x)|_{x = k}}$$

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ since the integral is over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Hence the cosine is $1$ and we have

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\delta(x-k)2^{-x}\ dx$$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{2^{-k}}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Yet my professor says it has to be

$$\frac{2}{3\pi}$$

How is that possible?

**EDITS**

Ok, understood my stupid mistakes about

$$\cos(\pi k) = (-1)^k$$

The question now is: there is the absolute value, hence shouldn't

$$|(-1)^k|$$

Be always positive??

Anni the additional factor, the series would become

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k 2^{-k} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi k) = (-1)^k$!!!!

Comment: @Rohan That is a VERY good point I was missing. But There is the modulus at the denominator, hence$$ |(-1)^k| $$ shouldn't be positive?

Comment: What is $\int_\epsilon^\infty\delta(x)\mathrm d x$ at $\epsilon=0$? Certainly it is 1 for $\epsilon<0$ and 0 for $epsilon>0$.

Comment: @DanRobertson That doesn't solve my doubt which is all about the modulus, not the integral.

Comment: @qbert 

$$\delta[f(x)] = \sum_{k = i}^{+\infty} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x)|_{x = x_i}}$$

Where $x_i$ are the roots of $f(x)$

Comment: @qbert https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function And besides, we aways studied it with the abs...

Comment: @qbert The absolute has to exist. The integral turns out to be $2/(3\pi)$ is $$|(-1)^k| = (-1)^k$$ which would be correct. But how?

Comment: @Winther I, frankly, understand anything of all this mess. An answer with details would be more appreciated!

Comment: see also [Integral over Dirac's delta distribution with variable upper limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2151378/289977).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series expansion for $\delta(\sin\pi x)$ is correct. I think your problem is because you are integrating a $\delta(x)$ from $x=0$. We write $H(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x\delta(\xi)\mathrm d\xi$ for the Heaviside step function. Now we know that for $\epsilon>0$, we have $\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon\delta(x)f(x)\mathrm d x = f(0)$ but one part of your integral (for the term where $k=0$) is $\int_0^\infty\frac{\delta(x)}\pi2^{-x}\mathrm d x$ which you claim is $\frac1\pi$ and I claim is $\frac{1-H(0)}\pi.$ And thus I think your professor is using the convention that $H(0)=\frac12.$ Then your answer would be too big by $\frac1{2\pi},$ which it is.

This correction gives the answer as:
$$\frac1\pi\left(1-H(0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\right)$$

Thus you get $\frac1\pi\left(1+1\right)$ and I get $\frac1\pi\left(\frac12+1\right)=\frac3{2\pi}$, the same as your professor.

Edit: You’ve changed your question to say that your professor thinks the solution is $\frac2{3\pi}.$ This is not the solution.

### Further details:

What is $\int_0^\infty\delta(x)\mathrm d x$? Well by the definition of $H$ above we have:
$$\int_0^\infty\delta(x)\mathrm d x =\left[H(x)\right]_0^\infty = H(\infty) - H(0) = 1 - H(0).$$ we leave $H(0)$ unevaluated because it is usually a convention. Some people choose $H(0)=1$, others $H(0)=0$ and others still choose $H(0)=\frac12$. I have heard rumours of some particularly applied physics calculations which depend on the value of $H(0)$ and required $H(0)=\frac12$ to get the right answer. Another vote in its favour is that it is then most “almost continuous” option in the following sense: It gives us that $H(x)=\frac12\left(\lim_{\xi\to x^-}H(\xi) + \lim_{\xi\to x^+}H(\xi)\right),$ the same property you get after a forward then inverse Fourier transform of a function.

Comment: First of all Dirac Delta integration can be from $a$ to $b$, whatever they are as long as the integration variable belongs in between. Secondly, I do have $\delta(x-k)2^{-x}$ and not $\delta(x)2^{-x}$, hence the integration is not $1/\pi$ but $2^{-k}/\pi$ which summed gives $2$ (over $\pi$). The question is about the modulus, which would give me $2/3$ as a sum, which is correct (it's not $3/2$ as I wrote). I don't really understand your answer.

Comment: Your integrand is a sum of delta functions. The part I am looking at corresponds to $k=0$, one of the sammands of the integrand

Comment: I, frankly, understand anything of this. A detailed answer would be more appreciated, also because I didn't even understand what is the final correct result...

Comment: @ArtificialIntelligence I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, and sorry for my being obnoxious and boring! Now I understood this and I'll bring into my mind forever!